# Память от динамического массива очищается не полностью

Tags: c++, память, динамические-массивы

В целях проверить, как работает выделение и очистка памяти написал такую программу:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int *big;

    cin >> size;

    big = new int[size];

    system("pause");

    delete[] big;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Сначала вводим, какой размер массива создать, потом удаляем и смотрим в отладке, сколько памяти занялось и освободилось.

И вот тут я заметил, что если ввести какое-нибудь не очень большое число, например 1024, то память для него выделяется, а после delete[] big, как показывает VS 2017, память так и остаётся занятой.

[image: Память занята]

Однако если написать число побольше то память выделяется и освобождается корректно.

[image: Память от большого массива освобождена]

Что с этим делать, это особенность выделения памяти в самой системе (использую Windows 7), или что-то не так с кодом?

Comment: Вы не туда смотрите. Вместо памяти процесса надо смотреть на разницу между срезами профилировщика памяти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не стоит напрямую ориентироваться на показания занимаемой процессом памяти. Своим `delete[] big;` Вы лишь даете операционной системе сигнал, что эта память больше не нужна и её можно использовать для других целей. А операционная система уже сама решит, когда действительно нужно что-то удалять.

Comment: `delete[] big;` как раз таки не дает операционной системе никаких сигналов, а уведомляет дефолтный аллокатор, что блок освобождается. А вот даст ли аллокатор сигнал операционной системе - это детали реализации.

Answer (score 5):

Библиотека времени выполнения языка С++ распределяет память не средствами ОС, а средствами своего внутреннего аллокатора, работающего внутри своего внутреннего пула. Она и не должна отдавать освобожденную память операционной системе. В традиционной реализации освобожденная память лишь помечается как "свободная" с точки зрения библиотеки времени выполнения. С точки зрения операционной системы такая память остается занятой. Поэтому нет смысла ожидать, что ваши выделения и освобождения памяти будут видны на уровне ОС.

Мгновенное возвращение освобожденной памяти обратно в ОС возможно разве что для освобожденных блоков, которые библиотека времени выполнения считает "очень большими". Это вы и наблюдаете в своем эксперименте.